# How to implement redis sessions expire in aiohttp

Tags: python, session, redis, aiohttp

I can't find redis session expiration implementation in aiohttp redis session. Session saved in redis but then i check ttl AIOHTTP_SESSION_c8a63762a87d4c01a64991e268c35f54 there is no ttl for session key.

How to implement expiration to avoid old sessions grow? i am think about set

```
expire 'AIOHTTP_SESSION_'+session.identity 300
```

On every request in session middleware, is it convinient way or I am missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see in the aiohttp-session documentation that [`RedisStorage` take a `max_age` parameter](http://aiohttp-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=max_age#redis-storage). This is used to set the expiration time of the associated redis key in [`redis_storage.py`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp-session/blob/master/aiohttp_session/redis_storage.py#L54)